# Referencing Auto Array Iterator in function

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

Here is a simple case where I'm finding the Max of an Array.

Im attempting to use an auto iterator in a array passed into my function.
When I utilize the same code in my function body no error.

The reference inside the function max creates a compile error

```
cpp:7:14: error: invalid range expression of type 'int *'; no viable 'begin' function available
        for (auto& x: array){
                    ^ ~~~~~
```

Here is my current code, i included a reference to normal usage in "normalMax" and a inline main body function.

I want to know why the iterator in the 'max' function produces an error

```
#include <iostream>
//max num

//causes an error
int max(int* array){
    int max = 0;
    for (auto& x: array){
        if (x >max)
            max = x;
    }
return max;
};
//normal behavior
int normalMax(int* array){
    int max = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
        if (i >max)
            max = i;
    }
return max;
};

int main(){

    int A[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int B[] = {5,6,10,100};
    int max = 0;
    //Works no Error
    for (auto& x: B){
        if (x >max)
            max = x;
    }
    std::cout <<max;
    //100
    normalMax(B);
    //max(B);
    //compile error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `array` is actually a pointer. Not like an array.

Comment: The ranged-for loop can't operate on a pointer, only arrays and certain classes.

Comment: Yes, `array` is a pointer, there is no way for the compiler to tell the size of the array. So you cannot use such loop.

Comment: thanks that makes a lot more sense. Is the solution to pass the array by reference?

Comment: @FirstTimer, Perhaps you want your function to take a `std::array`. Note, however, that `std::max_element` can already do this.

Comment: @FirstTimer Yes. You can, but that means your code only work for arrays of particular size.

Comment: Use `std::array<>` instead. It won't decay into a pointer like C-arrays.

Comment: @james, You could still make it a template that deduces the size (and type).

Comment: @chris You are right.

Comment: I found using it as 
I was referencing a pointer and not the array itself. I know theres more appropriate data structures but this works. 

    //reference
    int max(int (&array)[4]){
     int max = 0;
     for (auto& x: array){
      if (x >max)
       max = x;
     }
     max;
    return max;
    };

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to pass an array to a function so you the compiler can deduce its length, you'll need to pass it as reference not via a [decayed] pointer:

```
template <std::size_t N>
int max(int const (&array)[N]) {
    int max = 0;
    for (auto& x: array) {
        if (x >max) {
            max = x;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

As a side note: there is no semicolon after the definition of a function. Also, the function isn't particular useful as you should probably rather return the position of the maximum element rather than just its value: the position is determined implicitly anyway and may carry information. Of course, once you locate the correct position you should also return the proper best value which is actually the rightmost version of the maximum.

Comment: You can also use this `template<typename array_t>int max(array_t &a);`